# Javascript HTML5 Видео изменение(понижение) разрешения видео

Tags: javascript, html5, видео

Приветствую, лазил в интернете с данным вопросом и ничего толкового не нашел, а хотелось бы найти на чистом javascripte реализацию с понижением(изменением) качества видео.То есть заливается сначала видео в высоком разрешении, а потом, как на Ютубе, изменяется, без нужды указания нескольких источников видео.Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Во-первых, на *чистом* javascript это будет ООООООООЧЕНЬ медленно. Во-вторых, на клиенте или на сервере? Если на клиенте, то по-моему это бредовая идея, а на сервер можно просто поставить ffmpeg и не выпендриваться

Comment: Я не знаю где лучше, опыта в этом не имею, просто хочу реализовать ютубовскую фишку у себя.А не как большинство примеров в инете с указанием разных источников.

Comment: Вряд ли Вам кто-то это напишет. Это очень объемная функция с PHP или другим языком, за которую обычно платят. В общем, при загрузке видео оно обрабатывается на сервере с помощью плагина и создаётся несколько дубликатов видео в разном качестве, которые потом переключаются на плеере

Comment: Не подскажите, как правильно использовать все эти команды ffmpeg в PHP?